# how can i store multiple query result in one variable then manipulate it in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I  have tried to get the results using array individually.

say I have a 3 query

```
sql1=mysqli_query("select * from calls");
sql2=mysqli_query("select * from staff");
sql3=mysqli_query("select * from invoice");
```

what i want is to retrieve the result from those as a array and manipulate them in a single table column wise
please help me out

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. It's not quite clear what you want. Perhaps you could give us some sample data and what the resulting data would look like if it was working?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql code:
`SELECT c.*, s.*, i.* FROM calls as c, staff as s, invoice as i;` the result will be in one variable.

But i think you realy need `joins` or to manipulate specific data as (Count number of `calls` made by specific `staff` user etc.)

Comment: '$sql=SELECT Name,caller_id,ClientNr,sum(effective_duration)/60 as dd, sum(cost) as cst
FROM calls inner join invoiceclients
on  calls.id_client=invoiceclients.IDClient
and calls.client_type = invoiceclients.Type where  called_number REGEXP '^09' 
and call_start BETWEEN '2015-1-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-31 23:59:59' and ClientNr<>''
group by Name, ClientNr
order by Name'                                                  so i have 2 more query like this and at the end i want them in one table

Comment: I suggest to write the task and we will propose the solution, cause i don't really understand at the moment what do you need, or to be more specific, what do you need that for ?

Comment: thanks for your reply .i have a database  "calls, and invoiceclients"  table in that.i want to generate  repory for each client within the date range how much minutes he has used in onn-net,offnet,and isd call.i will just provide the date range from input.sorry for my bad english